# How `import` works in a Vue single file component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I am using a vue scaffolding tool to build an app. Say inside App.vue single file component. I am importing Vuex: `import Vuex from 'vuex';` But `vuex`  is inside the `node_modules` file. How does this work behind the scene? Why we can import files outside a module without specifying the relative path.

Comment: it has a root path. with `npm root` you can see the local root path and with `npm root -g` you can see the global path

Comment: The `import` path is resolved by Webpack (the build tool that Vue CLI uses), and the [module resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/) differs by the type of path. This works the same way in all JS files, not just for JS found in SFCs.

Comment: @Ifaruki Thanks for the tip. I find my global path is leading to somewhere in C drive, but it cannot be opened.

Comment: @tony19 Thank you so much. It helps a lot. I basically just take the vue CLI for granted without diving too deep into webpack.